# Merge Sort For Strings in MIPS Assembly

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, mips, mergesort

I want to write a code to sort an array consisting 64 strings with 10 characters using Mergesort algorithm.Since I'm new to assembly languages It's really hard for me to implement function calls and of course all tutorials in the internet are for the Intelx86 assembly,can anyone help me?

Comment: Googling "MIPS assembly tutorial" gives about 250,000 results. Try taking a look at the first few results.

Comment: Do you have a MIPS compiler? You could write it in C, and then compile it and check the assembly generated code. With GCC you can use the -S option to generate a `.s` file.